# From checkboxes, combo box and a text field to a txt file

Tags: java, swing

Let's say I have this code that adds a "subject" to an application that serves as an organizer. how do I write the things that a user inputs in a txt file that will again be read for the editing of the original input in case some editing might be needed. I tried searching on how do i get the data to a file but i failed. i hope you could help me. thank you.

```
    addSubject = new JPanel();

    contPanel.add(addSubject, "addSubject");

    JLabel lblSubject = new JLabel("SUBJECT");

    JLabel lblTime = new JLabel("TIME");

    JLabel lblDays = new JLabel("DAYS");

    subTxt = new JTextField();
    subTxt.setColumns(10);

    JComboBox thirdTime = new JComboBox();
    thirdTime.addItem("AM");
    thirdTime.addItem("PM");

    JComboBox secondTime = new JComboBox();
    for(int i=0; i<=59; i++){
        if(i<10)
    secondTime.addItem("0"+i);
        else
            secondTime.addItem(i);
    }

    JComboBox firstTime = new JComboBox();
    for(int i=0; i<=12; i++){
    firstTime.addItem(i);
    }

    subConfButton = new JButton("CONFIRM");
    subConfButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            int[]x = {};    
            subj.add(new Subject(subTxt.getText(), x, "nadf"));
            GridBagConstraints cons= new GridBagConstraints();
            cons.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0);
            cons.gridx = 0;
            cons.gridy = subj.size();

            subjTbModel.addRow(new Object[]{subTxt.getText()});
            subjectCombo.addItem(subTxt.getText()+ "");
            subTxt.setText("");
            cards.show(contPanel, "mainPanel");
        }

    });

    JButton cancelAdd = new JButton("CANCEL");
    cancelAdd.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            cards.show(contPanel, "mainPanel");
            subTxt.setText("");
        }
    });

    JCheckBox checkTuesday = new JCheckBox("TUESDAY");

    JCheckBox checkWed = new JCheckBox("WEDNESDAY");

    JCheckBox checkThurs = new JCheckBox("THURSDAY");

    JCheckBox checkFriday = new JCheckBox("FRIDAY");

    JCheckBox checkSat = new JCheckBox("SATURDAY");

    JCheckBox checkMonday = new JCheckBox("MONDAY");

    JCheckBox checkBox = new JCheckBox("SUNDAY");

    JComboBox fourthTime = new JComboBox();
    for(int i=0; i<=12; i++){
        fourthTime.addItem(i);
        }

    JComboBox fifthTime = new JComboBox();
    for(int i=0; i<=59; i++){
        if(i<10)
            fifthTime.addItem("0"+i);
                else
        fifthTime.addItem(i);
        }

    JComboBox sixthTime = new JComboBox();
    sixthTime.addItem("AM");
    sixthTime.addItem("PM");

    JLabel lblTo = new JLabel("TO");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are simply so many options it's not funny...

## You could

Use [`Properties`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) to store key=value pairs which provide `store` and `load` methods to make it easy to read and write

## You could

Use an XML file which allows you to store hierarchical data, while more flexible than `Properties`, it increases the complexity

See [Java API for XML Processing (JAXP)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/) for more details.

You could also use the JAXB (Java Architecture for XML Binding) which can be used to store object properties in an XML based structure.  Take a look at [Introduction to JAXB](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxb/intro/) for more details...

## You could

Simply roll your own, writing text to a file in what ever format you wanted. See [Basic I/O](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/) for more details

Comment: additional question, what can i do to make it as a "delete" option.

Comment: What do you mean?  If you mean remove one or more entries, then it will come down to the implementation, but the general approach is to read the file, make the modifications to the data and re-write the file.